# Asus p5k se/epu beeps every time a search finds nothing

Tags: motherboard

my problem is that every time I'm searching for a string (let's say on the browser, or notepad++, or even in NetBeans IDE) and there is no result, the motherboard beeps. This is really annoying and I couldn't find anything on the manual nor googling it.
Any suggestions? Did anyone have a similar problem?
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XP with no audio drivers suffer from this. Since it's not able to recognize any audio devices the only default output is the motherboard's buzzer. Once you install the drivers, no annying beeps should be played.